# How can hide the bottom border/table border in MDB bootstrap tabs like normal bootstrap tab

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I am trying to create MDB bootstrap tabs with menu items but no able to remove the bottom border

I need example like this bootstrat 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dropdown&stacked=h

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with `.mdb` files or Microsoft Access? Also, your question in general is very unclear. What are you aiming to do? In which environment are you working? What have you tried? What happened when you tried it? Answers to all of these will increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry for Microsoft Access it was typo. Actually I want to create a tabs menu in MDB design 4 but their tabs don't have feature like normal bootstrap so I just want to achieve that feature like this 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dropdown&stacked=h

Hope it will more clear for you